# Why if condition "(skaner.next() != int)" highlights as wrong?

Tags: java, if-statement

I wanna make a condition if somebody input a word the program will return "That is a string" if it is an integer the program will return "That is an integer ". What's wrong with my if condition ?

```
package folder;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner skaner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (skaner.hasNext()){
        if (skaner.next() != int) {
            System.out.println("That is a string" + skaner.next());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("That is an integer " + skaner.next());
        }
    }
    skaner.close();


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't edit your post to remove the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `skaner.next()` will return a `String` object whereas `int` is a primitive data type and therefore both are not comparable. To check if token returned by `skaner.next()` is an `int` or not, you can use `Integer.parseInt(skaner.next())` which converts `String` to `int` and throws a `NumberFormatException` if input is not a valid integer.

```
package folder;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner skaner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (skaner.hasNext()){
    String x = skaner.next();
    try {
        int y = Integer.parseInt(x);
        System.out.println("That is an integer " + y);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("That is a string " + x);
        }
    }
    skaner.close();
    }
}
```

Check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-string-is-a-valid-number-integer-or-floating-point-in-java/) for reference.

Comment: Okay, I've updated it, but after changing if statement like that it still shows me an error. I've tried also with `Integer.parseInt(skaner.next()) == true` but it's also wrong

Comment: For one thing, it is spelled "scanner" with a c.

Comment: "skaner" is Scanner in non-english form. That is the way how I called the variable, so it doesn't matter tho

Comment: You'll have to catch the exception and handle it separately. I have updated the answer with correct code.

Comment: @MXtrocin Your update is still invalid, because `Integer.parseInt()` returns the integer value, not a boolean. What exactly is your problem with using the code in this answer?

Comment: @user207421 Nothing. Just thought I can do this using if, else statements. Cheers!